# ASYNC AWAIT function returning undefined in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

I am currently new in nodeJS. I have to create a function which should wait for the result and after the result is populated it should return the data. This is my function

```
async function getReplyObject(reply_id, language, auto_translate){
    var new_sql1 = 'SELECT IFNULL((SELECT CONCAT(users.firstname," ",users.lastname) as owner_name FROM users WHERE users.id = messages.owner_id), "") AS owner_name,messages.forwarded, IFNULL(message_files.file_id, "") as file_id, IFNULL(files.thumbnail, "") as thumbnail, IFNULL(files.text, "") as audio_text, IFNULL(files.text, "") as original_audio_text, IFNULL(files.file_url, "") as audio_url, IFNULL(files.file_url, "") as original_audio_url, CONCAT(users.firstname," ", users.lastname) as sender_name , GROUP_CONCAT(messages.message SEPARATOR " ") as message, messages.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(messages.created_at) as unix_time, GROUP_CONCAT(messages.message SEPARATOR " ") as original_message , "" as group_files,IFNULL(messages.owner_id, 0) as owner_id,IFNULL(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(messages.forwarded_at), "") as forwarded_unix FROM messages JOIN users ON messages.sender_id = users.id  LEFT JOIN message_files ON messages.id = message_files.message_id LEFT JOIN files ON files.id = message_files.file_id WHERE messages.id = '+reply_id+' GROUP BY messages.group_id ORDER BY messages.id DESC';
    var b_sql = 'SELECT messages.forwarded, IFNULL(message_files.file_id, "") as file_id, IFNULL(files.thumbnail, "") as thumbnail, IFNULL(files.text, "") as audio_text, IFNULL(files.text, "") as original_audio_text, IFNULL(files.file_url, "") as audio_url, IFNULL(files.file_url, "") as original_audio_url, CONCAT(users.firstname, users.lastname) as sender_name ,messages.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(messages.created_at) as unix_time, messages.message as original_message , "" as identifier FROM messages JOIN users ON messages.sender_id = users.id  LEFT JOIN message_files ON messages.id = message_files.message_id LEFT JOIN files ON files.id = message_files.file_id WHERE messages.id = '+reply_id+' ORDER BY messages.id DESC LIMIT 20';
    await connection.query(new_sql1, (err, chats) => {
        if (err) {
            helper.sendError(NOT_FOUND_ERROR, res, errors, req);
            return;
        } else {

            await connection.query(b_sql, (err, result_set) => {
                result_set.forEach(function (key, i) {
                    if (key.type == 'audio') {
                        key.audio_url = base_url + '/api/chat/get_file?file_id=' + key.file_id + '&lang=' + language
                        key.message = 'Shared an audio'
                    } else if (key.type == 'location') {
                        key.message = 'Shared a location'
                    } else if (key.type == 'video') {
                        key.message = 'Shared a video'
                    } else if (key.type == 'contact') {
                        key.message = 'Shared a contact'
                    } else if (key.type == 'document') {
                        key.message = 'Shared a document'
                    }
                })
                var msgs = [];
                var indexs = [];
                var new_links = [];
                var audio_messages = [];
                var new_data = {};

                    itemsProcessed = 0;
                    chats.forEach(function (key, i) {
                        key.group_files = []
                        result_set.forEach(function (key2, j) {
                            if (key2.group_id == key.group_id) {
                                new_links.push(key2)
                                key.group_files = new_links
                            }
                        })
                        new_links = []

                        if (key.message != '' || key.message != null) {
                            msgs.push({
                                "text": key.message
                            })

                            indexs.push(i)

                        }
                        if (key.type == 'audio') {
                            if (key.audio_text != null) {
                                audio_messages.push({
                                    "text": key.audio_text
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    if (auto_translate) {
                        google.translateText(msgs, language, (json) => {
                            data = JSON.parse(json)
                            data.forEach(function (key, i) {
                                chats[i].message = key.translations[0].text
                                if (chats[i].type == 'audio' && chats[i].audio_text != '') {
                                    chats[i].audio_url = base_url + '/api/chat/get_file?file_id=' + chats[i].file_id + '&lang=' + language;
                                }
                                if(chats[i].type == 'contact' || chats[i].type == 'document'){
                                    chats[i].message = chats[i].original_message;
                                }
                            });
                            return JSON.stringify(chats[0])
                        });
                    } else {
                        return JSON.stringify(chats[0])
                    }

            })
        }
    });
}

var reply_id = 6308;
var current_user = {
    language: 'ar',
    auto_translate: 1
}

var reply_obj = getReplyObject(reply_id, current_user.language, current_user.auto_translate);
console.log(reply_obj);
```

But the issue is I can't get the async and await working properly. I tried it without async and await but the function was returning undefined because it wasn't waiting for the calls and stuff. What am I missing here?

Comment: You never called return. Also, if you're providing a callback I doubt a promise is being returned, which means you have an extraneous `await` as well.

Comment: @Aplet123 if I don't call return, what should I do? I'm confused between async await and promises. I need a to return the string. How can I do that?

Comment: What is `connection.query`? Does it return a promise? If it does, you probably should not pass a callback into it.

Comment: @Bergi var connection = mysql.createPool({
   connectionLimit: 10, 
   host         : config.DB_HOST,
   user         : config.DB_USER,
   password       : config.DB_PASSWORD,
   database       : config.DB_DATABASE,
 charset     : 'utf8mb4'
});


module.exports = {
  connect_database : function(){
    connection.getConnection(function(err,conn){
   if(!err) {
       console.log("Database is connected .....");
   } else {
       console.log("Error connecting database .....");
   }
  });

  return connection;
 }
};